# It's possible to sign in external users if Azure B2C tenant where tenant has restriction?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

1. I have a AD B2C multi tenant application
2. I have custom policy which have filtering on my tenant ([Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy))
3. Now on this tenant I invite new users from other tenants (I got "userEmail_contoso.com#EXT#@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com)

Why I can't to sign in with external user? It's possible to filtering the tenant but allow external users from same tenant to sign in?

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see `METADATA` in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-a-claims-provider) you shared:

```
 <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
```

We can see that it is using `common` endpoint. `common` endpoint means users with both a personal Microsoft account and a work or school account from Azure AD can sign in to the application. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document).

So although the personal Microsoft account is added into your tenant as a guest user now, it is treated as a personal account when it meets `common` endpoint. As a result, it is blocked from logging in.

In short, B2C multi-tenancy does not support guest user login.

In order to sign in as a guest user from your tenant, you should look into [Set up sign-in for a specific Azure Active Directory organization in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). You can see that the `METADATA` is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` in this document, which should treat your account as guest user.